# Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be markov moments such that $\tau \leq \sigma$

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, markov-process

Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be markov moments regarding filtering $\mathbb{F} = (F_t, t \in T), T \subset \mathbb{R}$. I need to prove that $\forall A \in F_{\tau}$, where $F_{\tau} = \left\{ A \in F: A \cap \left\{\tau \leq t \right\} \in F_t \right\}$, $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$:
$$
A \cap \left\{\tau \leq \sigma \right\} \in F_{\tau} \cap F_{\sigma}
$$
My approach was to prove that:
$$
(A \cap \left\{\tau \leq \sigma \right\}) \cap \left\{\tau \leq t \right\} \in F_{t}\\
(A \cap \left\{\tau \leq \sigma \right\}) \cap \left\{\sigma \leq t \right\} \in F_{t}
$$

for the second one I could write:
$
(A \cap \left\{\tau \leq \sigma \right\}) \cap \left\{\sigma \leq t \right\} \subset A \cap \left\{\tau \leq t \right\} \in F_{t}
$, since $A \in F_{\tau}$. But I have problems with proving $(A \cap \left\{\tau \leq \sigma \right\}) \cap \left\{\tau \leq t \right\} \in F_{t}$. Thanks for any help!

Comment: $
A \cap \left\{\tau \leq \sigma \right\}) \cap \left\{\sigma \leq t \right\} = A \cap \left\{\tau \leq t \right\} \in F_{t}
$ is not correct. You only have $\subseteq$.

Comment: @geetha290krm $(F_t, t\in T)$ is a family of $\sigma$-algebras such that $\forall s \leq t, F_s \subset F_t$. So $F_t$ is not a set, but $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: I meant $
(A \cap \left\{\tau \leq \sigma \right\}) \cap \left\{\sigma \leq t \right\} \subseteq A \cap \left\{\tau \leq t \right\} 
$

Comment: @geetha290krm oh, I undertand it. I will fix the mistake, but it still holds that $(A \cap \left\{ \tau \leq \sigma \right\}) \cap \left\{ \tau \leq t \right\} \in F_t$, since this set is a subset of $(A \cap \left\{ \tau \leq t \right\})$, which is in $F_t$

Comment: If one set belongs to $F_t$ why does every subset belong to it?

Comment: @geetha290krm maybe I'm not right, then could you provide your thought about the problem above, since now i don't have any good ideas how to solve it